# Are technical problems arising from social constraints on topic?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions

Sticking up for another closed question:

[Enforcing mutual uniqueness across multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24562733/425313)

It was closed as off-topic, without a definitive explanation.  It does have one highly voted comment:

> Social not technical question.

With elaboration by the same author:

> If you don't have the authority to change a schema that is a business problem not a technical problem. Voting to close. And we need another topic for close - social not technical.

Given that the question was closed and the reopen review should have occurred by now, it seems that many people agree with this.

Which to me seems misguided.  Arbitrary limitations may make it difficult or even impossible to answer a question, but sometimes you have to deal with them, and in this case it was solveable.

Is it valid to close a question for the sole reason that the OP's stated limitations are too onerous?

Comment: Almost all technical problems arise from social constraints, if you think about it.

Comment: Those comments were ridiculous and the close reason completely inappropriate. I've removed all of those comments and am frowning in the direction of the close voters.

Comment: I personally think this is not a reason to close as it is still a valid question, however I do think it is a fair reason to down-vote if one feels the op is demanding a ridiculous technical solution due to a broken business system.

Comment: @Vality I personally wouldn't downvote this, but I agree and applaud you for noting that close voting shouldn't be used simply when you don't like the premise of a question.

Comment: I would like to express my warm thanks to @BradLarson for taking this up on meta; I really appreciate his involvement. I was quite frustrated at the question's closure, but seeing that the community at large can still reach a sensible consensus has rehabilitated my attitude towards SO.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

I cast the final reopen vote - you're welcome.

I consider the first comment to be fundamentally flawed. It is a *technical* issue *because of* the social (business) issue. As one of the commenters says, this happens in real life: you need to apply a technical fix within tight constraints. In this case the technical problem is how to shape/massage/filter the data to fit the expected requirement. It's a fact of life that in the commercial world you can't always change the universe to fit your preferred view of it; often you have to work with what you've got.

In any case this sort of question closing happens occasionally - where a bunch of people deem a question needs to be closed, then another bunch of people take a longer look at it and decide it should be reopened.

Comment: Thanks, always reassuring to have meta swoop in and do a sanity check.

Comment: I've seen it happen a many times where "mob mentality" takes over. All it takes is for one person to comment why **they** think a post is not suitable and subsequent readers will just agree or throw their votes behind that view rather than evaluate it for themselves. Maybe I'm being a little harsh and it's more like a subconscious nudge in the first objector's direction but it definitely happens frequently.

Comment: Agree, the distinction being that the user is not asking us to help solve the social problem, they are asking for help solving the technical problem.

Comment: @indivisible it's better for a question to get closed too soon and then reopened than for it to stay open too long and attract answers that prevent auto-deletion. Reopening even pushes the question to the front page again. But yes, mob mentality does sometimes happen.

Comment: @indivisible another skew that you may have been subjected to - a close vote or a flag pushes the question into the close vote queue, which guarantees five more views from people who are _specifically_ asked if the question should be closed.

Comment: @JanDvorak, I see no issue with your second comment/point. Isn't that exactly what the Close Vote Flags & Queue are designed to do? I also don't necessarily disagree with your first point about over closing vs under closing questions. I was merely mentioning a trend I'd observed in the past. I've no strong opinions whether or not it is a net benefit or detriment to the site(s) overall. Both could be easily argued.

Comment: @JanDvorak: That is the kind of attitude that bothers me. Is it really more important for the site to be free of non-auto-deleteable questions, than to foster a sense of community where newer (or established) members can feel comfortable asking questions without getting voted off? The feedback I get from new users of StackOverflow is that this site has become too hostile; and repeatedly getting their questions closed off for silly reasons eventually throws them off from participating further (and contributing to its growth).

Answer (score 18):

I'm going to play devil's advocate for a moment.

Sometimes people post questions and they imply there's some social/business/technical reason for not doing something, but they never state what that reason is. It's often important to know that reason in order to write an answer that meets the needs of the person asking the question. Otherwise you write an answer that you think will be a solid, usable solution. But then it turns out you wasted your time because they didn't let you know all the limitations.

I don't think it warrants a closing for not having provided those details up front, but I will downvote a question if someone went through the effort of posting a good solution that was nullified by hidden requirements. And of course, I leave a comment saying that they need to express the question as completely as reasonably possible up front in order to receive a good solution.

In this case, the question should have not been closed, and I appreciate they said the schema can't be modified up front. But then if you note the comment below by the asker:

> I can create new objects, constraints, triggers, etc. I cannot alter
>   the columns of the existing tables (which will continue being inserted
>   to and updated).

That's the type of thing that I think should have been included in the question up front had the question been fully thought through. On one hand, he says he can't change the schema, but then he says he can change objects, constraints, triggers. [Wikipedia defines schema as](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_schema):

> In a relational database, the schema defines the tables, fields,
>   relationships, views, indexes, packages, procedures, functions,
>   queues, triggers, types, sequences, materialized views, synonyms,
>   database links, directories, XML schemas, and other elements.

Therefore, someone might have assumed from the beginning that he wasn't allowed to modify these things, resulting in much more complicated answers.

Comment: "hidden requirements" -- such as, "thanks but I cannot use `qsort`, my teacher doesn't allow that". Sigh ..

Comment: I agree that saying "I cannot change the schema" was incorrect and potentially misleading; I actually meant to say "I cannot make breaking changes to the schema". I've since corrected the question per this post.

Comment: @Douglas But my issue isn't specifically with your question. It's that people often leave out these key details, yours just happened to serve as a convenient example. Unfortunately, I don't see a good solution for getting people to include all relevant details. But maybe someone else will have an idea...

Comment: Like you, I tend to downvote careless questions that are amended to introduce new (formerly hidden) requirements that nullify the validity of posted answers. If the question is still fresh and I anticipate an ambiguity in its details, I would do what [mrjoltcola](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24562733/enforcing-mutual-uniqueness-across-multiple-columns#comment38045067_24562733) did and post a comment asking for clarification.

Comment: However, whilst I agree with your stand, I need to clarify that this issue wasn't the reason behind the question's former close. The members who voted for closing disagreed with my restriction on *breaking* changes.